# Creating a new Envelope and applying a template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the API to create an envelope and then I pass that envelopeID to the Sender View and apply a template. What is happening is that a new envelopeID is being created and the template is applied. Can I not create a new envelopeID and pass that in or do I need to let API create one in the Sender View call and retrieve that one back ?

Comment: Whenever you create an envelope you specify, at creation time, whether it's from a template or from a local document. As soon as a draft envelope is created OR an envelope with status set to `sent`, the DocuSign automatically generates the envelopeId.  What exactly is your use case you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks... I actually backed out the creation process  and added the template at creation time and it works fine.

Comment: Ok cool, I've posted my comment as an answer, can you accept please?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create an envelope you specify, at creation time, whether it's from a template or from a local document. As soon as a draft envelope is created OR an envelope with status set to sent, the DocuSign automatically generates the envelopeId.